# How to translate "grinchy" (Weihnachtsapathie)?

Tags: translation, single-word-request

Maybe the [grinch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grinch) is not that well-known, as for *grinchy* to be translated by making up the respective adjective (*grinchisch, grinchmäßig*, or whatever the correct term is).

Is there a German word, a (preferably a funny way, as in order to stress the joke character) way of putting together

> nicht weihnachtsbegeisterter Mensch
>   Weihnachtsverderber (don't know whether it's correct, but seems aggressive)     ?

Comment: The Dr. Seuss books and characters are nearly unknown in Europe. So, this seems to be a non-translateable pun. The closest I can come up with is the Austrian *Krampus*, a kind of Christmas daemon and the mean counterpart of St. Nikolaus. Not sure if you could form an adjective from it that that would be understood.

Comment: @tofro, Oh no please do not mix up Krampus, which is a Salzburg-local tradition associtated with St. Nikolaus, with Christmas. They do not have anything in common. The Krampus is more closely related with the Perchten appearing in the twelve-nights between Christmas and Epiphany - those are daemons.

Comment: @rexkogitans: Salzburg? Goes much further than that, but yet, it's traditionally associated with St. Nicholas.

Comment: @Ingmar, ok Austria and neighbours, but definitely not Christmas, not even Christian.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently the fictional *The Grinch* is not well known in Germany. The closest translation I can think of would be

#### Weihnachtsmuffel

This expression was also used for movie or book titles. A *[Muffel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muffel_(Person))* can be associated with all kind of activities: *Faschingsmuffel, Partymuffel, ...*

Comment: *Muffel wird heute meist als geschlechtsneutrales Schimpfwort für die Eigenschaften Übellaunigkeit und Engstirnigkeit verwendet.* Seems the perfect term up to *Schipfwort* (which maybe is, nevetheless, quite relative). I hope the *Weihnachts-* part of the word soften it enough.

Comment: From my experience *Schimpfwort* would be a bit too strong. A *Muffel* still is somwhat likeable but can of course also be at times a *Spielverderber*. As always, it depends on usage.

Comment: How the Grinch Stole Christmas! (the 1960s cartoon version) has been shown in German TV at least as far back as the early 1980s. And then probably never again, which was a huge bummer for me, then only about six years old... But "unknown" is certainly not correct.

Comment: I love that this comes from „*mit vollem Mund kauen*.“

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek: Something can be "unknown" in a country even though there was an obscure TV show about it. That does not preclude some people happen to know the unknown thing, just like some people in Germany will know the [mythical Indonesian Garuda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garuda) or the [American supermarket chain Costco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costco). Nonetheless, when you ask random people in Germany about Garuda, Costco, or the Grinch, the vast majority will probably have no idea what you are talking about, thus showing the thing in question is virtually unknown.

Comment: I am a _Morgenmuffel_. And by far I don't recognize that as a _Schimpfwort_. It simply means you're not supposed to talk to me before 9 a.m.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Taking into account that in the early 80s Germany had exactly three TV channels, all of them publicly operated and none of them broadcasting more than about 12 hours per day, it is quite plausible that _anything_ broadcasted back then had a quite significant market share. Thus my attack on the use of the word "unknown" is valid, a phrase like "not well known" would convey the meaning without suggesting that the Grinch was unheard of except by "contamination" by external sources.

Comment: There were five channels because you could receive the two East German TV channels in most of West Germany and vice versa. And the Grinch is easily misidentified with Oscar the Grouch from early Sesame Street episodes.